# "SSL doesn't have a valid keystore" error when trying to connect to Datomic Cloud

Tags: clojure, jetty, datomic

I am trying to shift over a project to use the new [datomic cloud](https://docs.datomic.com/cloud/index.html). I've created the stack through the AWS dashboard, and even been able to connect to it in a plain clojure repl with the required dependencies. But I've been having a difficult time getting a connection to work from within my project.

At first, I ran into a bunch of dependency conflicts -- indeed that may still be the root problem here -- so I added some exclusions to my inclusion of the datomic project in my `project.clj`:

```
 [com.datomic/client-cloud "0.8.50"
  :exclusions [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-io
               org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util
               commons-logging
               commons-codec]]
```

Then when I tried to connect in the `lein repl` with

```
(require '[datomic.client.api :as d])
(def cfg {:server-type :cloud
          :region "us-east-2"
          :system "<sysname>"
          :query-group "<sysname>"
          :endpoint "http://entry.<sysname>.us-east-2.datomic.net:8182/"
          :proxy-port 8182})
(def client (d/client cfg))
```

I ended up with the following error:

> 2018-05-13 20:36:01.593:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:nREPL-worker-1: FAILED SslContextFactory@56f447c4(null,null): java.lang.IllegalStateException: SSL doesn't have a valid keystore>
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: SSL doesn't have a valid keystore`

This one stumps me. Here is a pastebin with the full stack trace: https://pastebin.com/cRGyVmnT. I am guessing that there may be a problem with the wrong version of jetty getting called, but I'm not sure what next steps to try. Thoughts?

Comment: I would try to make an exclusion for Jetty not in `com.datomic/client-cloud` but in the other dependencies that require it, so that you get a Jetty version that is compartible with Datomic Cloud.

Comment: I don't totally follow what you mean. Any chance you could provide a short example?

Comment: Run `lein deps :tree` to see which other libraries require Jetty. Then, remove `[org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-io org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util]` from the exclusions of the `com.datomic/client-cloud` dependency you listed in the text of your question and add these exclusions for the other libraries that depend on Jetty.

Comment: Okay, I'll give the shot. Is the effect of this change that the version of the jetty packages specified by the datomic cloud library would be given preference?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution for this based on the suggestion by @Aleph Aleph in the comments to the question above. What I did was add exclusions to the package that had dependencies conflicting with `datomic/cloud-client`.

I looked at this conflicts by looking more closely with `lein deps :tree | grep jetty`. It showed the following in particular:

```
[ring "1.6.3" :exclusions [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-client org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-http org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util]] -> [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.6.3"] -> [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server "9.2.21.v20170120"] -> [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-
io "9.2.21.v20170120"]
 overrides
[com.datomic/client-cloud "0.8.50"] -> [com.datomic/client "0.8.40"] -> [com.datomic/client-impl-shared "0.8.34"] -> [com.cognitect/http-client "0.1.83"] -> [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-client "9.3.7.v20160115"] -> [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-io
 "9.3.7.v20160115"]
 and
[com.datomic/client-cloud "0.8.50"] -> [com.datomic/client-impl-shared "0.8.34"] -> [com.cognitect/http-client "0.1.83"] -> [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-client "9.3.7.v20160115"] -> [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-io "9.3.7.v20160115"]
 and
[com.datomic/client-cloud "0.8.50"] -> [com.datomic/client "0.8.40"] -> [com.cognitect/http-client "0.1.83"] -> [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-client "9.3.7.v20160115"] -> [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-io "9.3.7.v20160115"]
```

As is evident there, the dependency coming from `ring` called `ring/ring-jetty-adapter` contained some package versions overriding those in datomic cloud. So I added the following, fixing the problem:

```
[ring "1.6.3"
 :exclusions [ring/ring-jetty-adapter]]
```

Comment: Turns out that this didn't solve my problem. I'd only tested in a repl. The jetty exclusion broke the ring server. So I'm back trying to figure out how to resolve the dependency conflicts.

Comment: In the output above it seems that you're getting `jetty-io` dependency from `ring`. If that's not what you want then add this artificat to the `:exclusions` vector.

Comment: Maybe a less error prone option would be to discard exclusions completely and declare an explicit dependency on `ring/ring-jetty-adapter` (in your `project.clj`) using the proper version (I guess `9.3.7.v20160115` or similar which is compatible with datomic)

Answer (score 3):

If you specify more recent dependency versions for `jetty-server` and `jetty-client` it should finally work.
This is what worked for me:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.9.0"]
             [ring/ring-core "1.7.0-RC1"]
             [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.7.0-RC1"]
             [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server "9.4.9.v20180320"] 
             [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-client "9.4.9.v20180320"] 
             [com.datomic/client-cloud "0.8.52"]]
```

For a complete demo see https://github.com/ezmiller/datomic-ring-dep-conflict/pull/1/files

Comment: +1. This is what worked for me. I don't like having dependencies in my deps vector that aren't directly needed by my app, but oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround for me was to replace the ssl-context-factory implementation with alter-var-root + to use the following dependencies instead:

```
org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-http         {:mvn/version "9.2.24.v20180105"}
org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-io           {:mvn/version "9.2.24.v20180105"}
org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util         {:mvn/version "9.2.24.v20180105"}
org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-client       {:mvn/version "9.2.24.v20180105"}
```

Downside is now it trusts everything, but perhaps something optimal configuration can be found.

```
   (defn ssl-context-factory-replacement
      ^SslContextFactory [{:keys [trust-all classpath-trust-store trust-store-password trust-store validate-hostnames]}]
      (SslContextFactory. true))`enter code here`

    (alter-var-root
     #'cognitect.http-client/ssl-context-factory
     (constantly ssl-context-factory-replacement))
```